# Object relational mapping in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

> I have 2 tables named 'employees' and 'dataentry'. I need to set the employee_id column in employees table as primary key, and also employee_id column in dataentry as a foreign key of employees.employee_id. How can I do this in groovy domain class.

```
here is my employees.groovy model class
```

```html
package com.standout.utilityapplication

import java.util.Date;
import com.standout.utilityapplication.Dataentry

class Employees {

static mapping = {
     table 'employees'
  version false
   }

        static hasMany = [employee_id:Dataentry]
  String employee_id
  String employee_name
  String team
  Long contact_no
  String designation

  
  
  static constraints = {
   
   employee_id(nullable: false,maxSize:10)
   employee_name(nullable: false,maxSize:100)
   team(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   contact_no(nullable: true,maxSize:10)
   designation(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   
  }

}
```

```
and here is my dataentry.groovy model class
```

```html
package com.standout.utilityapplication
import com.standout.utilityapplication.Employees

class Dataentry {

 static mapping = {
  table 'dataentry'
  version false
   }
     static belongsTo = [employee_id:Employees]
  String employee_id
  String team
  Date receipt_dt
  String restaurant_name
  int number_of_persons
  float amount
  Date bill_submitted_dt
  String reimbursed
  char presented_bank_fl
  Date presented_bank_dt
  String create_id
  Date create_dt
  String mod_id
  Date mod_dt
  
  
  static constraints = {
   reimbursed(nullable: true)
   presented_bank_fl(nullable: true)
   presented_bank_dt(nullable: true)
   mod_id(nullable: true)
   mod_dt(nullable: true)
  }

}
```

> Please tell me how to make a mapping with cascaded

Answer (score 2):

Something akin to this should get the entities joined. Convention is to name an entity in the singular, not a plural (Employee, not Employees):

```
class Employee {
    static hasMany = [dataentries:Dataentry]
    static mapping = {
        id name:'employee_id'
    }
}

class Dataentry {
    static belongsTo = [employee:Employee]
}
```

Let the system take care of the details.